# Adding <meta-data> tags to manifest file causes namespace error?

Tags: android, namespaces, android-manifest

When I add `<meta-data>` tags to my manifest file the app refuses to run and throws a ManifestMergerFailureException aswell as a org.w3c.dom.DOMException.

Manifest without tags:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:name=".StarterApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/sf"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TimelineActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_timeline" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Manifest with `<meta-data>` tags, generates namespace error:

```
<application
    android:name=".StarterApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/sf"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:="APPKEY" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
        android:value="CLIENTKEY" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    android:="APPKEY" />
```

Class "value" missing ;)